# color bar plot depending on the x value with R

Tags: r

I have bar plot realize with R and I would like to color the bars with different colors depending on the value of the x-axis. For example I would assign for for the bar with x = 1 the color orange, for the bar with x = 2 the color yellow, for the bars 3=<x=<5 the color light green and for the bars from 6 to 28 the color dark green. How do I enter this condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign colors to the bars via the `color` parameter of the `barplot()` function. The argument takes either a single color (if you want all bars to look the same) or a vector of colors.

In your case, given the data stored in a matrix `m`, you would write:

```
barplot(m,color=c("orange","yellow",rep("lightgreen",3),rep("darkgreen",23)))
```

Comment: If I use ggplot function? Can I do the same?

Comment: Yes, you could. By adding the parameter `+scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange","yellow",rep("lightgreen",3),rep("darkgreen",23)))` to your plot